# How do I specify a start date using time at a particular time of the day with yfinance

Tags: python, stock, yfinance

Please am trying to get the stock date at a specify time of the date adding the time of which i want the stock data to be gotten from as well to so far i did something like this but i keep getting error saying data   `- F: Data doesn't exist for startDate = 1666286770, endDate = 1666287074`

this is my code below

```
def watchlist():
    timezone = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    print(type(timezone))
    aware = dt.datetime.now(timezone).time()
    print(aware) 
    global pastTime
    pastTime = dt.datetime.now(timezone) - dt.timedelta(minutes=5)  # time of 5minutes ago
    print(pastTime)
    for x in ticks:
        toStr = str(x)
        syb = yf.Ticker(toStr)
        data = pd.DataFrame(syb.history(interval="1m",period='1d',))
        data2 = pd.DataFrame(syb.history(interval="1m",period='1d',start=pastTime))
        if data['Open'].sum() < data2['Open'].sum():
                     print(data['Open'].sum())
                     print(data2['Open'].sum())
                     print('Watch stock')
        else:
            print(toStr, 'Proceed to sell with robinhood')
   
   
watchlist()
```

[Screen shot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBSEG.png)

Comment: Both due dates are with future dates. `import datetime;dt=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1666286770);print(dt);2022-10-21 02:26:10`

Comment: Okay i see so what do you suggest i do to get the current datetime and datetime of 5minutes ago?

Comment: I am not sure why the time zone is necessary, but if the time zone is to be converted after acquisition, acquisition can be done in the following way first. `now_ = dt.datetime.today();start=dt.datetime(now_.year, now_.month, now_.day, now_.hour, now_.minute - 5)`